# Delphi VCL Styles. Как сохранить стиль нажатой кнопки, когда она теряет фокус?

Tags: delphi, vcl

Решил попробовать RAD Studio 10, в нем есть крутая фишка с нативными скинами. Но проблема в чем - стиль применился, отлично. Есть кнопка, когда ее жмешь, она получает фокус, применяется стиль нажатой кнопки. Собственно вопрос - как сохранить это состояние, точнее стиль нажатой кнопки, когда она теряет фокус?

Comment: Зачем вам вводить пользователя в заблуждение нажатой кнопкой если она не нажата? Попробуйте свойство `Down := True` (емнип оно не у всех типов кнопок бывает).

Comment: Пользователь делает выбор 1 из 3 вариантов. Когда он жмет на кнопку (кнопка получает фокус) стиль у нее становится отличным от других, и переходит к другим полям формы. Нужно визуальное отображение выбора, и хотелось именно тем-же стилем, что был при нажатии. Down нашел у speedbutton, но не сработало

Comment: Как вариант, поищите как отправить кнопке свойство, что она нажата, через WinAPI. Еще варианты: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46934591/how-to-make-delphi-tbutton-control-stay-pressed

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо, Kromster за ссылку, там был найден один из ответов, который подошел.
В общем, нужно использовать `TSpeedButton`, выставить ему свойства:

```
AllowAllUp := true;
GroupIndex := 1;
```

Так все кнопки (среди которых надо выбрать одну, например) будут в 1 группе, и при нажатии одной из них - она будет утапливаться, остальные переходить в обычный статус.

Comment: Рад помочь. Здорово что вы нашли и запостили ответ сами. Ловите +1!